# Trying to avoid infinite loop if input is not an integer

Tags: c

UPDATE BELOW

I need to test if an input is an integer, and if it is then continue doing something.

If the input is not an integer I need to print an error message and quit.

The method I'm using is `scanf` will return the number of read items, in my case I want it to return 1. So I test if `scanf` returns 1, and execute the rest of my code.

But, for some reason when `scanf` doesn't return `1` I run into an infinite loop

Code:

```
/*
 * Read in a number of values to read and then print the average
 * of those values.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "tfdef.h"
#define DEBUGGING 1;

int main() {
    int expected;
    int count;
    double sum;
    int value;
    int flag;

    while (flag = scanf("%d", &expected) != EOF) {
#ifdef DEBUGGING
        printf("flag: %d  expected: %d\n", flag, expected);
#endif

        if (flag == 1) {
            sum = 0;
            for (count = 0; count < expected; count++) {
                scanf("%d", &value);
                sum += value;
            }
            printf("Average of %d values is %.2f\n",
                   count, count != 0 ? sum / count : 0.0);
        } else {
            printf("Error! Can't read number of expected values.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The following code seems to work except the case where the initial input is a number followed by letters. For example:

Input: `eeee33333`
Printed: `Error! Can't read number of expected values.`

Input: `333eeee`
Printed: `Debug1 flag:1   expected: 333`

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tfdef.h"
#define DEBUGGING 1;

int main() {
    int expected;
    int count;
    double sum;
    int value;
    int flag;

    while (flag = scanf("%d", &expected)) {
#ifdef DEBUGGING
        printf("Debug1 flag: %d  expected: %d\n", flag, expected);
#endif
        if (flag == EOF) { 
#ifdef DEBUGGING
            printf("Debug2 flag: %d  expected: %d\n", flag, expected);
#endif
            return 0; 
        }
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        if (flag == 1) {
            sum = 0;
            for (count = 0; count < expected; count++) {
                scanf("%d", &value);
                sum += value;
            }
            printf("Average of %d values is %.2f\n",
                   count, count != 0 ? sum / count : 0.0);
        }
    }
    printf("Error! Can't read number of expected values.\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that `flag = scanf("%d", &expected) != EOF` is equivalent to `flag = (scanf("%d", &expected) != EOF)`. Maybe not what you want? Also note that if you enter a non-integer then [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) will return `0` and not `EOF`.

Comment: You must find a way to flush the input buffer, or the program will keep trying to read the `.` decimal point or whatever. But I would input with `fgets` and then apply `sscanf`, that way you can easily dump the rest of the input.

Comment: Lastly, you might want to consider using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and `sscanf` instead.

Comment: add a `break`; into `else` scope

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see.. So should I test if flag is EOF in another if statement? Will try that now ...

Comment: @WeatherVane I can only use very basic functions, scanf, printf, if, while. fgets and sscanf I can not use. Another requirement is no use of break or continue statements ...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please see above.

Comment: I assume it's for a school assignment (or similar)? Otherwise such restrictions would be unrealistic and stupid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Correct, an introductory C class. I agree, that the restrictions are unrealistic, as things like isdigit exist.

Comment: `scanf` is evil. I'm afraid you cannot do fulfill the requirements with `scanf`.

Comment: Are you allowed to write your own input function? Since you use `scanf` in two locations, it makes sense to have a function that inputs an `int` checking to see if it is followed by a `newline`. And as commented, the way to use `scanf` is `if(scanf("%d", &expected) != 1)`. Or, your function can input char by char, checking each is a digit, and build the `int` value yourself.

Comment: Are you allowed to use [`fgetc` or `getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) to read single characters? How about [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)?

Comment: As this is an introductory class, i guess they are expecting `fflush(stdin)`. Even though that is wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm leaning toward writing my own input function as we are allowed to. The beginning code block was given to us, and we were asked to modify it to accommodate certain situations (Ex: Expected number of numbers is some garbage)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if by getc you mean getchar, yes. The functions we have at our disposal are if, while, for, scanf, printf, getchar. Browsing through similar problems it seems like this is easily remedied by using the functions you mentioned (atoi was mentioned a lot), however I cannot...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Made an update, please see updated post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @WeatherVane Made an update, please see updated post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje fflush(stdin) is a function we have not learned yet.

Comment: You **must** check **every** `scanf`.

Comment: Had a few minutes over, so I [created a program](https://gist.github.com/pileon/87c6c9648f27d60b3cd13db34456ef81) that should do what you want, while still following the rules and limitations. Please don't copy it verbatim, but you are welcome to be "inspired" by it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this problem is to read the input with `fgets()` and parse it with `sscanf()`, but the reason you get an infinite loop is this: your test is incorrect:

```
while (flag = scanf("%d", &expected) != EOF)
```

`flag` receives the result of the comparison between the return value of `scanf` and `EOF`... You probably meant to write this instead:

```
while ((flag = scanf("%d", &expected)) != EOF)
```

But if the user types something that cannot be parsed as an `int`, such input lingers in the `stdin` buffer and `scanf()` will keep attempting to parse it in vain.

Try this approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getnumber(int *valp) {
    char line[80];
    char last;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        flag = sscanf(line, "%d %c", &expected, &last);
        if (flag < 1) {
            printf("Input is not a number: %s", line);
            continue;
        }
        if (flag > 1) {
            printf("Extra characters after number input: %s", line);
            continue;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return EOF;
}

int main(void) {
    int expected;
    int count;
    double sum;
    int value;

    while (getnumber(&expected) != EOF) {
        sum = 0;
        for (count = 0; count < expected; count++) {
            if (getnumber(&value) == EOF) {
                printf("Error! Can't read number of expected values.\n");
                break;
            }
            sum += value;
        }
        printf("Average of %d values is %.2f\n",
               count, count != 0 ? sum / count : 0.0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I see now how the test is written incorrectly.   The functions fgets() and strtol() aren't at our disposal. This is an introductory C course and the instructor explicitly stated to use only functions we have learned in the class (with the extra condition of not using break of continue statements in this particular problem) I know these seem like unrealistic and unnecessary parameters but that's how it is...

Comment: @StephenCadiz: if `scanf()` returns 0, you must deal with offending input and skip it. A simple way to do this is `scanf("%*s");` that will read and discard a sequence of non white space characters.  `scanf()` is very quirky, easy to misuse and a common source of software flaws. It is too bad it is still among the first library functions beginners see and use when learning the C language.

Comment: Thank you for writing that piece of code, I had to look up some functions but I think I can follow your train of thought.  Further reading corroborates your statement about scanf, there are whole articles detailing why it shouldn't be used... Alas all I have available to me to read input is scanf and getchar at the moment. @chqrlie

Comment: @StephenCadiz: one classic problem with `scanf()` is the use of `%s` conversion specifiers: unless you have complete control over the input, this is as bad as using the infamous `gets()` function: sufficiently long input strings will cause a buffer overrun.  See if your course warns about this and suggest using a length specifier to limit the input to one less than the size of the destination array:  `char buf[20]; n = scanf("%19s", buf);...`